# Algebraic Algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Let $A$ be an algebra over a field $K$. Consider the following statements.

(1) If $A$ is an integral domain and algebraic over $K$, then $A$ is a field.

(2) If $A$ is a field and is contained in an affine $K$-domain, then $A$is algebraic.

I know these statements to be true as proof's of them were provided to me by an instructor. I was told that I could find examples that show that the hypothesis in both (1) and (2) cannot be omitted in order for each statement to be true. Can anyone please help see that this is the case. Thank you.

- this is not a homework assignment.

Comment: What do you mean by "the hypothesis"? Both of your statements have two hypotheses. Is the question to show that both hypotheses are needed?

Comment: Yes indeed. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, there are four counterexamples you need to find. Already it's nontrivial progress just to state clearly what these are, as follows:

1. A $K$-algebra $A$ which is an integral domain but not a field. What integral domains do you know how to construct?
2. A $K$-algebra $A$ which is algebraic over $K$ (I assume this means every element of $A$ satisfies a polynomial with coefficients in $K$) but not an integral domain. Adjoin the root of a polynomial to $K$ and ask yourself when the result is *not* an integral domain.
3. A $K$-algebra $A$ which is a field but not algebraic. What fields do you know how to construct? Do you know how to construct fields with transcendental elements?
4. A $K$-algebra $A$ contained in an affine $K$-domain which is not algebraic. What affine $K$-domains do you know how to construct?

Comment: I see, Thank you for that. I will try to work on this.